# Find '.dng' image resolution using Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to get the '.dng' image resolution but I am getting incorrect resolutions. But I am getting correct resolutions for '.jpg' images

```
img = Image.open("01109677451NasiLemakBiasa.dng")
width = img.width 
height = img.height
print(width, height)

# Output 256 171
```

The actual resolution of the image (01109677451NasiLemakBiasa.dng) is 1024 x 683

Please help me to get the correct width and height of the image

Comment: Can you provide the image?

Answer (score 4):

`PIL` doesn't read DNG files, nor does it like 16-bit per channel RGB. I think you'll need something like [rawpy](https://pypi.org/project/rawpy/)

```
import rawpy

path = '/Users/mark/Desktop/RAW_LEICA_M8.DNG'
with rawpy.imread(path) as raw:
    rgb = raw.postprocess()

print(rgb.shape)       # It's a Numpy array
```

**Sanple Output**

```
Out[9]: (2638, 3920, 3)
```

---

Another option is `Exiftool`, which you can install like this:

```
pip3 install PyExifTool
```

and use like this:

```
import exiftool

with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
    metadata = et.get_metadata('/path/to/RAW_LEICA_M8.DNG')

print(metadata)

{'SourceFile': '/path/to/RAW_LEICA_M8.DNG',
 'ExifTool:ExifToolVersion': 12.0,
 'File:FileName': 'RAW_LEICA_M8.DNG',
 'File:Directory': '/path/to',
 'File:FileSize': 10575296,
 'File:FileModifyDate': '2021:08:16 08:54:30+01:00',
 'File:FileAccessDate': '2021:08:16 09:56:33+01:00',
 'File:FileInodeChangeDate': '2021:08:16 09:56:31+01:00',
 'File:FilePermissions': 644,
 'File:FileType': 'DNG',
 'File:FileTypeExtension': 'DNG',
 'File:MIMEType': 'image/x-adobe-dng',
 'File:ExifByteOrder': 'II',
 'EXIF:Make': 'Leica Camera AG',
 'EXIF:Model': 'M8 Digital Camera',
 'EXIF:Orientation': 1,
 'EXIF:Software': 1.107,
 'EXIF:Artist': '',
 'EXIF:SubfileType': 0,
 'EXIF:ImageWidth': 3920,            <--- HERE IS THE WIDTH
 'EXIF:ImageHeight': 2638,           <--- HERE IS THE HEIGHT
 'EXIF:BitsPerSample': 8,
 'EXIF:Compression': 1,
 'EXIF:PhotometricInterpretation': 32803,
 'EXIF:StripOffsets': '(Binary data 1315 bytes, use -b option to extract)',
 'EXIF:SamplesPerPixel': 1,
 'EXIF:RowsPerStrip': 16,
 'EXIF:StripByteCounts': '(Binary data 989 bytes, use -b option to extract)',
 'EXIF:XResolution': 300,
 'EXIF:YResolution': 300,
 'EXIF:PlanarConfiguration': 1,
 'EXIF:ResolutionUnit': 2,
 'EXIF:CFARepeatPatternDim': '2 2',
 'EXIF:CFAPattern2': '0 1 1 2',
 'EXIF:LinearizationTable': '(Binary data 1244 bytes, use -b option to extract)',
 'EXIF:WhiteLevel': 16383,
 'EXIF:DefaultCropOrigin': '2 2',
 'EXIF:DefaultCropSize': '3916 2634',
 'EXIF:BayerGreenSplit': 500,
 'EXIF:AntiAliasStrength': 0,
 'EXIF:Copyright': '',
 'EXIF:ExposureTime': 12,
 'EXIF:ExposureProgram': 1,
 'EXIF:ISO': 160,
 'EXIF:ExifVersion': '0220',
 'EXIF:CreateDate': '2007:08:02 22:13:49',
 'EXIF:ShutterSpeedValue': 11.3137084989848,
 'EXIF:ExposureCompensation': 0,
 'EXIF:MaxApertureValue': 2,
 'EXIF:MeteringMode': 2,
 'EXIF:LightSource': 0,
 'EXIF:Flash': 0,
 'EXIF:FocalLength': 50,
 'EXIF:FileSource': 3,
 'EXIF:SceneType': 1,
 'EXIF:WhiteBalance': 0,
 'EXIF:DigitalZoomRatio': 0,
 'EXIF:FocalLengthIn35mmFormat': 67,
 'EXIF:SceneCaptureType': 0,
 'EXIF:ImageUniqueID': '00000000000000000000000000000147',
 'EXIF:SelfTimerMode': 0,
 'EXIF:DateTimeOriginal': '2007:08:02 22:13:49',
 'EXIF:FocalPlaneXResolution': 3729,
 'EXIF:FocalPlaneYResolution': 3764,
 'EXIF:FocalPlaneResolutionUnit': 2,
 'EXIF:TIFF-EPStandardID': '0 0 0 1',
 'EXIF:DNGVersion': '1 0 0 0',
 'EXIF:UniqueCameraModel': 'M8 Digital Camera',
 'EXIF:ColorMatrix1': '1.0469 -0.5314 0.128 -0.4326 1.2176 0.2419 -0.0886 0.2473 0.716',
 'EXIF:ColorMatrix2': '0.7675 -0.2195 -0.0305 -0.586 1.4118 0.1857 -0.2425 0.4007 0.6578',
 'EXIF:CameraCalibration1': '1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1',
 'EXIF:CameraCalibration2': '1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1',
 'EXIF:AsShotNeutral': '0.4750637903 1 0.7966159382',
 'EXIF:BaselineNoise': 1,
 'EXIF:BaselineSharpness': 1,
 'EXIF:CameraSerialNumber': 3106091,
 'EXIF:CalibrationIlluminant1': 17,
 'EXIF:CalibrationIlluminant2': 21,
 'MakerNotes:UserProfile': 1,
 'MakerNotes:SerialNumber': 3106091,
 'MakerNotes:WhiteBalance': 0,
 'MakerNotes:LensType': '33 3',
 'MakerNotes:ExternalSensorBrightnessValue': -5.16796875,
 'MakerNotes:MeasuredLV': -4.359375,
 'MakerNotes:ApproximateFNumber': 4,
 'MakerNotes:CameraTemperature': 19,
 'MakerNotes:ColorTemperature': 5515,
 'MakerNotes:UV-IRFilterCorrection': 0,
 'MakerNotes:CCDVersion': 0,
 'MakerNotes:CCDBoardVersion': 1,
 'MakerNotes:ControllerBoardVersion': 0,
 'MakerNotes:M16CVersion': 0,
 'MakerNotes:ImageIDNumber': 327,
 'Composite:CFAPattern': '2 2 0 1 1 2',
 'Composite:ImageSize': '3920 2638',
 'Composite:LensID': '33 3',
 'Composite:Megapixels': 10.34096,
 'Composite:ScaleFactor35efl': 1.34,
 'Composite:ShutterSpeed': 12,
 'Composite:CircleOfConfusion': 0.0224225825588557,
 'Composite:FOV': 30.0756572109854,
 'Composite:FocalLength35efl': 67}
```

---

Sample raw images downloaded from [Raw Samples](https://www.rawsamples.ch/index.php/en/).